# how to show the popup message on Exit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button  something like this what should I do?

```
<input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="JavaScript:window.location.href='../index'"/>
```

On Exit I am going to Other view..

On click on Exit I need to display popup window saying Are you sure you want to Exit? with Ok and Cancel buttons

anybody tell me out to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

```
<input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="confirmBox()" />

function confirmBox(){
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Exit?')){
    window.location.href = '../index'
  }
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
<input type="button" value="Exit" id="exit" />

$('#exit').click(function(){
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Exit?')){
     window.location.href = '../index'
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks If I have somethign like this what should I do..?

Answer (score 2):

For an input:

```
<input type="submit" id="exitApplication" value="Exit"/>
```

Using jquery you can:

```
$("#exitApplication").click(function(){
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?")
  if(!answer){
      //false when they click cancel 
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: i am confused why you have chosen the id as `delete`.

Comment: An id is just a unique identifier for an html element.  You can call the id anything you want that is valid within the html specification.   I changed it to exitApplication, but it makes no difference what this id is.  I had this code handy from an application I am working on so I pasted it in and delete was the ID I was using but you are welcome to change it.  Just if you change id to something else make sure you change the jquery selector as well to reflect as I did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

If you've this...

```html
<input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="JavaScript:window.location.href='../index'"/>
```

... there are a couple of ways to achieve this.

Both Chris & Sarfraz solutions work. What you can do as well as to add a `confirm(...)` dialog in the page's `onbeforeunload` event.

```html
<html>
  <body> 
    Click this button to go to Google's homepage.
    <input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "Are you sure?";
      }
    </script>  

  </body>
</html>
```

This will guarantee that, not only when the user clicks the Exit button, but also when s/he tries to navigate away from the page (For example, clicking the "Back" button in the browser.), `onbeforeunload` event will be triggered, and prompt the user to make sure s/he really wants to leave the page.

`confirm(...)` returns `true` if the user says "Yes, I want to leave the page."

Comment: Just keeping this Body code will work for any button? in the view? or only for navigating? please can you provide me comeplete code Ken thanks i am confuse..

Comment: My mistake. It's window's onbeforeunload, not body's onbeforeunload. I've edited my post to reflect it. (Comment won't let me post code nicely.)