# How to launch a popup window when tab closes, or when new address typed in?

Tags: javascript, popup, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to launch a popup from certain pages. I want users to see the popup only when:

a) they close the browser tab
b) they hit the browser's Back button
c) they go to a page other than the next step in the purchase path - basically, when they go to any URL that does not contain the string "/checkout/".

I've looked at popup examples that load body onUnload, and that's a bit too global. I just want a popup - a true actual popup - to launch if they try to leave the checkout path.

I've looked at several questions on StackOverflow, but none of them quite seem to answer my question. The onBeforeUnload mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753963/1634459 might work...MIGHT...but I'm not totally sure how to implement it with the conditions I listed above.

...help?

Here's the popup window code I'd like to use:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var win=null;
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll,pos){
if(pos=="center"){LeftPosition=(screen.availWidth)?(screen.availWidth-w)/2:50;TopPosition=(screen.availHeight)?(screen.availHeight-h)/2:50;}
settings='width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no';
win=window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
if(win.focus){win.focus();}}
function CloseNewWin(){if(win!=null && win.open)win.close()}
window.onfocus=CloseNewWin;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go; I wrote this for the marketing team at a previous job. You should be able to adapt it pretty easily; just update the URL and params as appropriate.

This code will open a popup when the user leaves the page, unless they leave by submitting the checkout form. (If you have more than one form on the page, which you shouldn't in a checkout flow, you will need to fix that as well.)

```
var nag = function () {

    return {
        // assume the user is going to leave, get ready to pounce!
        doWant: true,

        // FALCON PUNCH
        deploy: function () {
            if (nag.doWant) {

                var width = 449;
                var height = 298;

                args = "width=" + width + ",";
                args += "height=" + height + ",";
                args += "location=0" + ","
                args += "menubar=0" + ","
                args += "resizable=1" + ","
                args += "scrollbars=0" + ","
                args += "status=0" + ","
                args += "titlebar=0" + ","
                args += "toolbar=0" + ","
                args += "hotkeys=0"

                var demo_window = window.open("YOUR_URL", "main", args);

                try {
                    demo_window.focus();
                } catch (err3) { };
            }
        },

        // oh, off to step 2? that's cool. carry on.
        ignore: function () {
            nag.doWant = false;
        }
    }
} ();

window.onunload = nag.deploy;
document.forms[0].onsubmit = nag.ignore;
```

If you want to be able to STOP the user from leaving the page, I can help you with that update.

Comment: Our eventual choices to the users are going to be: continue on with the checkout process; go view this other freeSchwag that we've got; or no thanks, go to wherever-else-it-was (but not get another popup). It looks like your example incorporates that, so I'll need to explore that a little. Would this code go in the head or in the body of a page?

Comment: if that comment had HTML it didn't come through.

Comment: You can drop this script pretty much anywhere and it should work. That said, scripts should go at the end of the body if you aren't running a JS MVC-type app.

Comment: Can this code be modified to dynamically fit the size of its contents? (Generally an image.) Ah, and I forgot to tell you - for right now, there's not a need to stop them from leaving the site. We just want to bring them back to the site. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mathletics I'm trying to run this code locally, but when I close the browser tab nothing happens. I've put your code above between script tags, just above the /body tag; and I've changed the YOUR_URL to popup2.html (the name of a file in the exact same directory). I left everything else exactly the same. I'm fairly new to JavaScript, though, so it's possible that I should have changed something else that I didn't...but why is this not working locally? (It doesn't even launch a popup window when I close the entire browser, not just that one tab.)

Comment: Is the popup being blocked by your browser? When I run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuH3j/2/) I get a blocked popup.

Comment: Ah - I didn't realize that this was using jQuery. That could very well be my FIRST problem to check. Back after I do that...

Comment: BACK Okay @Mathletics , I had the page call jQuery 1.8.2, and had the rest of your fiddle code between the BODY tags, exactly as you had it (except I put the JavaScript between SCRIPT tags, and changed "YOUR_URL" to "popup2.html" which exists in the same folder.) Then I opened the page in Firefox, made sure that popups would -=not=- be blocked, and closed that browser tab. Nada. Tried again, but closed the whole browser...nothing. What else should I check?

Comment: The script doesn't use jQuery. Are you getting any errors in the console log? Do you have a public link to your implementation that I can look at?

Comment: Eh. Found it. For some reason, a question mark had gotten put after the last line in your fiddle JavaScript when I copied it into my page. Classic case of User Error, Too Much Blood in the caffeine stream. So now I do see a popup whenever I reload the page, and whenever I move away from the page (ie, typing in www.yahoo.com.) So my next question is: the code you provided - how is that licensed? I'm working on a commercial project, and want to make sure that my using it is kosher/legal.

Comment: Hi @Mathletics I've got some more questions: 1) is this code free for commercial re-use? I don't want my employers to get into legal hot water if I use this in their project. 2) is it possible to change the window size to fit its contents? (And BTW, thank you for all your help. I've learned a lot, which, to me, is just as important than the immediate solution - if not moreso.)

Comment: It's my code. It's unlicensed, but there was no IP agreement at my previous job. Modify it to be able to dynamically size and I'm sure you're fine.

Comment: Is it possible to streamline that code so that all the args are just included after window.open, and the code will still work? I tried typing "var demo_window = window.open("popup.html", "dontgo", "status=no,height=200,width=250,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");" and removing the bit about "args" (your code was var demo_window = window.open("popup.html", "dontgo", args);) but the popup didn't appear when I tried that. (It seems awfully long. I'm trying to come up with ways to streamline the code. And we've ditched the auto-resize, yay...)

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DuH3j/3/ I've moved the args to one line as an array, then join them upon execution. It's a compromise to compress without sacrificing all readability. I've also added optional sizing to the `deploy` method. See if that hepls.

Comment: I'd like to add that "streamlining" code at the expense of readability is stupid. If you're that concerned about character counts, use coffeescript. (And minify your production files!)

Comment: Actually, I was streamlining the code because while width and height would be potentially changing, the other options never would - having them called out separately as arguments seemed excessive. What is the reason for inputting those as an array, rather than a string?

Comment: Readability, and array joins are faster than string concatenation (though at this scale the benefits are negligible.)